# Почему мобильный хотспот Windows 10 не видит статические IP адреса?

Tags: windows-10, wifi, hotspot

Создаю точку доступа с помощью мобильного хотспота Windows 10. Все клиенты, подключенные с помощью DHCP отображаются в списке подключенных устройств, а клиенты со статическим IP не отображаются. Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Список подключенных устройств заполняется из списка лиз DHCP.